# "Фехтоваться" или "фехтовать"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Добро пожаловать, или посторонним вход воспрещён":

> *И это не первое нарушение Иночкина: в день приезда он фехтовал**ся** на палках, а вслед за ним все стали фехтовать**ся**. Даже девочки.*

Привычен вариант *"фехтовать".* Почему тут *"фехтоваться"?* Так тоже говорят? Или это устаревший вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему тут "фехтоваться"? Так тоже говорят? Или это устаревший
>   вариант?

Нет, употреблён не устаревший вариант, это художественная особенность. С одной стороны, речевая характеристика товарища Дынина, начальника лагеря, не отличавшегося особой культурой речи, хотя и ставившего себя высоко - ведь он начальник. С другой стороны, это игра слов - каламбур, ведь Костя Иночкин не фехтовал в классическом смысле слова, он в понятии начальника **дрался**, изображая фехтование, потому и получилось **фехтовался**.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке:

**ФЕХТОВАТЬ,** Заниматься фехтованием. Он прекрасно фехтует. Ф. на рапирах, на шпагах, на эспадронах.

**ФЕХТОВАНИЕ,** ср. 1. Система приёмов владения холодным оружием в рукопашном бою. Учебное пособие по фехтованию.

Но глагол ***фехтоваться*** существовал раньше, наряду с глаголом **фехтовать**, например:

Жорес брал атаками, а Клемансо **фехтовался** софизмами. [Андрей Белый. Между двух революций (1934)]

Вот порядочные манеры, хорошие знакомства, уметь **фехтоваться**, верхом ездить, записаться членом яхт-клуба, ― это я понимаю. [Н. Г. Гарин-Михайловский. Студенты (1895)]

Мы **фехтовались** утром, вместе завтракали ...[В. П. Мещерский. Мои воспоминания (1897)]

Брендон был красив собой, ловок, прекрасно танцевал, **фехтовал** на рапирах, (1870)]

Но потом глагол **фехтоваться**  вышел из употребления, и  к 1964 году, когда снимался фильм, он скорее всего уже был **устаревшим.**

Но почему т. Дынин, начальник пионерского лагеря, использует его? Не исключено, что таким образом выражено **ироническое отношение к персонажу,** который не умеет правильно употреблять  красивое "книжное" слово. Тем более, что палка ― это не холодное оружие.

О том, что когда-то им пользовались представители **дворянской интеллигенции,** уже было, вероятно, основательно забыто.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Comment: Пожалуйста.  Но  я не совсем поняла вот что: слово "фехтоваться"   существует  сейчас или нет? Или его вообще никогда не было. Я не совсем поняла это из ответа Людмилы. И почему т. Дынин его употребляет. он-то откуда его взял? Придумал сам или слышал от кого-то? Какова истинная история слова - вот что интересно. Вы всё о нем узнали?

Comment: Нет, не всё, прочитал только ваши с Людмилой ответы. Из Ваших ведь примеров видно, что в XIX и начале XX века оно употреблялось. А откуда т. Дынин его взял, можно только догадываться... Может, слышал от старшего поколения, но употребил его неумело?

Comment: *Но я не совсем поняла вот что: слово "фехтоваться" существует сейчас или нет? Или его вообще никогда не было. Я не совсем поняла это из ответа Людмилы.* Согласен, это действительно непонятно из её ответа. Хотя из первой фразы можно предполагать, что такой вариант раньше был, но он не использован сознательно как устаревший.

Comment: Что тут можно сказать? Жаль, что вы так быстро закрыли тему. Вопрос интересный, дискуссионный (когда и почему слово ушло из языка),  а теперь уж, скорее всего, никто и ничего больше не добавит.

Comment: По Фасмеру, фехтова́ть пришло к нам через польск. fechtować (się) из нем. fесhtеn «фехтовать, сражаться», в разговорном варианте закрепилось фехтоваться, если речь идёт о процессе боя (как биться, сражаться, драться) , а если речь о владении приёмами борьбы - то фехтовать. Фехтоваться, видимо, закрепилось не без помощи книги "УСТАВЪ
СТРОЕВОЙ КАЗАЧЬЕЙ СЛУЖБЫ" , написанной на южном диалекте казаков: "§ 219. По командѣ: СТАНОВИСЬ, фехтующiйся доворачивается въ пол-оборота налѣво такъ, чтобы носокъ и каблукъ правой ноги были впереди каблука лѣвой..."

Comment: Потом значения соединились в одном книжном слове фехтовать, а фехтоваться осталось как разговорное и для воссоздания обстановки фехтования того времени ( как историзм), сейчас тоже используется, когда речь идёт о боях саблистов и шашистов (бои на саблях и шашках) для воссоздания среды казаков.

Comment: Я закрыл тему? Хм... Я просто не знаю, что ещё спросить, сказать, но с интересом читаю, например, что пишет Людмила.

Comment: Давайте я Вам помогу. Во-первых, попросите Людмилу перенести материал в ее ответ с пометкой дополнение (чтобы смысл дискуссии был ясен). Во-вторых, сведения касаются происхождения слов и их значения в определенное историческое время. Сейчас же языковой статус их неясен. В словаре Кузнецова слова фехтоваться нет, а где есть? Это историзм? Но они относятся к группе устаревших слов. Специальная  лексика? А где ее найти? Разговорного статуса у него тоже нет.

Comment: Вот бы о чем хотелось спросить. А потом перейти к т. Дынину. Какая ситуация была с этим словом в 1964 году, почему его использовал автор? Если персонаж знает исторические слова, то он вовсе не бескультурен, а очень  удачно (отчасти иронично) применил его. Тогда это положительная характеристика нашего героя. Вы видите, сколько вопросов возникает. Может быть, и другие участники присоединились бы, помогли бы своими ответами. А если вопрос принят, то обычно люди не отвечают на него. Вот это и значит закрыть тему или сделать ее неудобной для обсуждения.

Comment: *А если вопрос принят, то обычно люди не отвечают на него. Вот это и значит закрыть тему или сделать ее неудобной для обсуждения.* Действительно, не подумал об этом. :( @Людмила: если я пока отменю принятый ответ, не обидетесь? Согласен, было бы хорошо, если бы Вы перенесли материал из комментариев в свой ответ.

Comment: *Если персонаж знает исторические слова, то он вовсе не бескультурен, а очень удачно (отчасти иронично) применил его.* Кстати да, мне такая версия кажется правдоподобной. Людмила пишет, что Дынин не отличался особой культурой речи, но мне показалось, что обычно он всё-таки говорит грамотно. Например, слово "премировАть" с таким ударением он произносит правильно, а я узнал об этом ударении всего несколько месяцев назад (не ставлю себя в пример, просто сделал вывод, что слово не очень простое).

Comment: Да, Артем, т. Дынин не так уж прост. Кстати, что меня огорчает, так это малое количество отвечающих на форуме. Кого-то нам здесь не хватает, чтобы воодушевить и расшевелить участников, сделать их более активными и заинтересованными. Вы обратили внимание? Кроме того, новые люди, которые начинали отвечать, потом почему-то перестают это делать. Наверное, их надо как-то поощрять, проявлять к ним внимание, голосовать за них. Вот в чем тут дело?

Comment: *Кроме того, новые люди, которые начинали отвечать, потом почему-то перестают это делать. Наверное, их надо как-то поощрять, проявлять к ним внимание, голосовать за них.* Наверно, и правда надо. Я сам был активен, а потом заходил только от случая к случаю. Теперь опять почему-то интерес возрос. :)) Не все новички только, к сожалению, прислушиваются к другим участникам, уважительно относятся друг к другу.

Comment: Возможно, это от недостатка понимания наших требований. Но были и вполне вежливые люди, но сейчас они не проявляют активность. Почему пропадает интерес, как сделать форум интересным? Может быть, каждый работает за себя, нет коллектива, где люди слушают друг друга и ценят мнение других. И как обычно: кто виноват и что делать? Может у них спросить на Мете? Перенести туда разговор?

Comment: Не знаю даже, правильно ли это (насчёт Меты), но я бы попробовал. В любом случае не побьют же за это. :))) Вот grizzly, например, не исчез (помню, как он только появился). Долго жалел, что Вера (Vera) пропала. С ней было интересно! Серж как-то тоже редко выглядывает из норы (ничего обидного не подразумеваю, про нору шутка!).

Comment: Да, к людям привыкаешь, как к друзьям хорошим. Иногда даже не верится, что коллектив наш виртуальный и между нами многие километры могут быть. И Вы, Артем, не исчезайте больше, а Сержу надо записочку написать, чтобы чаще отвечал. С другой стороны, может, времени не хватает.

Comment: *И Вы, Артем, не исчезайте больше...* Спасибо за пожелание, постараюсь!))  Да, конечно, может просто времени не хватать и у него, и у других.